# using protobuf-net with WCF client and a java server

Tags: java, .net, interop, protobuf-net

We are looking to communicate between a .net client and a java server using 'Protocol Buffers'.

Ideally would would like to use protobuf-net through WCF since all the rest of our communications to other services goes through the WCF stack.

I have a proof of concept .net WCF client talking to a .net WCF server using protobuf-net endpoint behaviour and that seems to work fine.

**My question** is how would we go about configuring the java server to send the proto-buf to our WCF client? I.e. Do we need to expose the java server to WCF as a SOAP services and send the proto-buf over that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that scenario, I would strongly recommend using *regular* SOAP for the protocol, and exposing a `byte[]` or `Stream` (or whatever works) as the payload - and then handle the encoding in your application.

The serializer hooks in WCF mean that it is *largely* similar to a `byte[]` payload (on a per-parameter/result basis), but I can't guarantee that it will be easily deconstructed outside of WCF.

Besides... if you describe it as a SOAP message that includes a BLOB, you are being truthful to SOAP.

Comment: Thank you for the help. We really, really want to keep the WCF stack, so will give it a go trying to reconstruct the payload as Jon suggested and fall back to regular SOAP if we can't. Will post our findings either way.

Comment: @Edward - it would still be WCF - it just wouldn't have strong type definitions in the WSDL (just `byte[]`)

Answer (score 1):

If your WCF client is using a protobuf-net endpoint, it's not using SOAP is it? I can't say I've used protobut-net personally, but I understood that it was an *alternative* to SOAP. Basically, have a look at the protocol it uses and implement the same protocol as a servlet. I would expect that to be reasonably simple, to be honest.

If it works and you can contribute the servlet as open source, I suspect you're not the only one who'd like to do this :)

Comment: I **think** the endpoint is exposed as a SOAP endpoint, protobuf-net adds a WCF endpoint behaviour that encodes/decodes the soap message body into and from Base64. 

I'm guessing I would need to mimic that behavior on the Java side

Comment: @Edward: If it really *is* doing that, that's probably pretty easy on the Java side - you'd just need to expose a soap service with a single method accepting a byte array and returning a byte array. I suggest you use Wireshark or Fiddler to verify this as the first step.